# Build a model with 2 Foreign Keys to the Same Table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, data-modeling

Lets say I have a `User` model and now I want to add a `Friend` model. I want to name my FK fields `RequestorID` and `ResponderID`. What data annotations or fluent api mappings do I need to accomplish this and prevent EF from autogenerating its own columns?

```
public class Friend
{
    public int FriendID { get; set; }
    public int RequestorID { get; set; }
    public int ResponderID { get; set; }
    public int FriendStatusID { get; set; }
    public DateTime User1RequestDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime User2ResponseDate { get; set; }
    public virtual FriendStatus FriendStatus { get; set; }


    public virtual User Requestor { get; set; }
    public virtual User Responder { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
public class Friend
    {
        public int FriendID { get; set; }
        public int RequestorID { get; set; }
        public int ResponderID { get; set; }
        public int FriendStatusID { get; set; }
        public DateTime User1RequestDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime User2ResponseDate { get; set; }
        public virtual FriendStatus FriendStatus { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("RequestorID")] //fixed
        public virtual User Requestor { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ResponderID")]
        public virtual User Responder { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: You have a syntax error on the first data annotation, but that worked. Thanks.